# Magento 2: Multiple Maximum Order Total value in Cash on Delivery

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

The requirement is to set up cash on delivery "Maximum Order Total" values specific for each country.

For example in my case for Saudi Arabia, Maximum Order Total of 1500 and for Other Gulf countries, Maximum Order Total of 1000. How can I do this?

- Saudi Arabia - 1500
- Other Gulf countries - 1000

In admin dashboard, there is only one common "Maximum Order Total" field which applies for all countries.